# Change Parameter Value with a Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I got the task to build a report, that shows the information of three different months on one page. The current month, current -1 and current -2.
The challenge is, that i have `@month` already in my Dataset1. This cannot be changed.
I have another Dataset for the month-parameter:

```
WITH Kalender 
AS (SELECT DateAdd(m,-2,DateAdd(d,1-DAY(DateAdd(d,-1,Convert(date,GETDATE()))),DateAdd(d,-1,Convert(date,GETDATE())))) AS [Datum] 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(m, 1, [Datum]) 
    FROM Kalender 
    WHERE DATEADD(m, 1, [Datum] ) <= DateAdd(d,-1,Convert(date,GETDATE()))
   )
   
Select Monat = convert(varchar(4),Year([Datum])) + right('00' + convert(varchar(2),Month([Datum])),2)
FROM Kalender
ORDER BY Monat desc
```

The month format should look like this: 202102 - that's how the date is converted in the query of Dataset1.

I wanted to create three different tablix, one for each month. Is there any possible way, to set a filter on each tablix that changes the month-parameter value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set filters on Tablixes, yes. Filter can't change the value of a parameter though and it would make no sense for it to. Each time the parameter's value is changed the data needs to be refreshed. If the parameter was passed, the data returned, and then the filter changed said parameter, the parameter would have to be repassed, the data returned, and then the filter would change said parameter, which would have to be repassed, the data returned, and then the filter would change said parameter, which would have to be repassed, the data...

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve, but can you not just use an expression in your tablix filter that replicates the expressions in your dataset query? If this does not help, show the current report design, any parameters you have and all dataset queries with sample data if applicable.